# How to create a user account in Windows Vista using VBScript?

Tags: windows-vista, vbscript

How to create a user account in Windows Vista using [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)?

I'm using the following script. It's working fine on Windows XP, but gives me an error on Windows Vista:

```
strUserName = "username"
strPassword = "password"
strComputer = "."
set objSystem = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer)
set objUser = objSystem.Create("user", strUserName)
objUser.SetPassword strPassword
objUser.SetInfo
```

Comment: please give us more info about the error you get!

Answer (score 3):

I am able to run this script on my Vista box just fine, and it creates the user.

I suspect you might be having a UAC issue. [This article](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/vbscripts-and-uac-elevation/) provides some options for elevating the permissions of your script.

Option 1 – the code relaunches itself with elevated permissions:

```vb
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
   Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   'Pass a bogus argument, say [ uac]
   objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & _
      WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " uac", "", "runas", 1
Else
   'Add your code here

End If
```

Option 2 – a separate launcher script:

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strPath = FSO.GetParentFolderName (WScript.ScriptFullName)
If FSO.FileExists(strPath & "\MAIN.VBS") Then
     objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", _
        Chr(34) & strPath & "\MAIN.VBS" & Chr(34), "", "runas", 1
Else
     MsgBox "Script file MAIN.VBS not found"
End If
```